# How to execute sql file in docker?

Tags: mysql, lamp

I have **lamp** project and try to run it in the Docker compose. The app is working but doesn't have connection with mysql. The reason: **sql** file does not execute and the database is not created. When I go into the container and run the sql file manualy, then everything works good.

```
 version: '3.7'
services:
  
  db:
    build:
      context: ./database
      dockerfile: Dockerfile    
    container_name: data36
    environment:      
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password123      
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=php_mysql_crud
    volumes:
      - ./database/script.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/script.sql
      -  mysqlvol:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    networks:
      - app

  php:
    container_name: php8
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html/
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    networks:
      - app
    depends_on:
      - db
      
volumes:
 database:
 mysqlvol:

networks:
  app:
    driver: bridge
    


Dockerfile:


FROM mysql:5.7.17

ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD password123

COPY script.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

RUN chown -R mysql:mysql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

EXPOSE 3306

CMD ["mysqld", "--character-set-server=utf8mb4", "--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci"]
```

How can I execute **script.sql** in container ???

Comment: in dockerfile: `RUN mysql < /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/script.sql`

Comment: @Kristian-ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
ERROR: Service 'db' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c mysql < /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/script.sql' returned a non-zero code: 1

Comment: try `RUN mysql -u root -ppassword123 < /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/script.sql`

Comment: @Kristian mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
E   ---------- Maybe I need to create entrypoint.sh ?